# Error when inviting a user to google cloud

Tags: google-apps, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to add a new member on my google-cloud project but i can't make it work.

The link inside the auto-generated email from google is well linking to the page where the user can confirm/decline the invitation inside a modal.

But when this user click "confirm" an error message appear inside the modal but disappear immediately - so quickly i can't read it. As a result i can never grant access to my project to this user.

In my browser debugger here is the error i can trace (some values are forged) :

```
"NetworkError: 400 Bad Request - https://console.developers.google.com/m/teams/acceptinvitation?xsrf=AFE_nuNg_V8394FDKjdfkjkjwKDFXDVg%3488T6J5783&authuser=1&action=accept&pid=apps~myproject-hosting&receive_updates=false"
```

This user has a custom domain which is a google-apps managed domain. I specify this because its the only kind of users we cannot invite to the project.

No problem for adding users with `@gmail` account.

From the google-cloud documentation i can read this :

> If you are using a Premier or Google Apps domain, the administrator for your domain should first create the Google account from within the Users panel of your Admin Console.

I don't understand this sentence as my user is off-course already listed in my domain.

Answer (score 0):

This might be expected behavior from the App Engine. I know that once you link you application to a specific domain via Google Apps, it becomes very hard to add people from outside that domain to your application.

I know that you can create a google group, enable "out-of-domain" members to that group. Then you can add that group to your project. Then you can add his email to the group, which should give him access to the project.

Only caveat here is that, if your domain is google.com, you will not be able to use this workaround, and this may require help from support.

Comment: Thank you Patrice for the answer but there is no way i can allow a group to access my google-cloud project. Only possible action is to "Add member" then enter his email address.

Comment: AFAIK, a google group has an email address like "groupname@googlegroups.com". You should be able to add that

Answer (score 0):

Well i finally did it.

Google seems to have fixed the flashing error message making it impossible to read.

Now it display something like this : "Contact your administrator to enable AppHosting admin on your account".

This is done has follow :

- Login to your main google-app account on http://admin.google.com
- Go to "App"
- Go to "Additional Google services"
- Enable "Google Developers Console" for everyone

Now my user can be invite to the google-cloud project.